# Is there a way to use JSR-303 (hibernate) annotations and modify the Message using {0} {1} syntax?

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

Is there a way to use JSR-303 (hibernate) annotations and modify the Message using {0} {1} syntax?  It seem that using a Spring Validator gets you this:

String args[] = {"mark", "is", "cool"};
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "aboutYou", "aboutYou.required", args);

So I can change the message.  However, if I use annotations, I cannot use the message args.  I understand that there are limited (min, max, etc.) args to use, but we want to make a generic statement and add some text.

java:
@NotEmpty (message="validation.name.required")
private String name;

properties
validation.name.required={0} is required...

Output:

Full name is required.

Answer (score 1):

In your interface:

```
public @interface Test{

    int value() default 7;

    String message() default "{MESSAGE}";    
}
```

In your messages file:

```
MESSAGE=Testing param {value}
```

Output:

```
Testing param 7
```

As found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-errormessage) and [here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Validator_Reference_Guide/validator-defineconstraints-own.html), works for validators which do not use hibernate also.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you're using Spring, this might help:  http://blog.inflinx.com/2010/03/10/jsr-303-bean-validation-using-spring-3/

You can also get the annotation-parameters (like min- and max- annotation-values for @Size) from ConstraintViolation< Object> -object (javax.validation.Validator.validate(Object) -method returns a Set< ConstraintViolation< Object>>) with .getConstraintDescriptor.getAttributes(), if you want to parameterize them to the messages with the {0} {1} etc. -notation (the numbers might be something else than 0 and 1 for @Size for example, I don't have the code at hand, but I seem to recall that there was some other data "in between" in the Map that getAttributes returned).

Note that in my case I used programmatic validation (getting Validator-object from Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator() and using it to validate an object with JSR-303 -annotations), extracted the needed data from the Set of ConstraintViolations (if the Set was not empty), put the data in a custom Exception-class and threw it out of the service, all the way to a org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver -implementation, that would gather the localization keys and message parameters from the exception object and localize the messages via MessageSource, so this might not be exactly what you're looking for.